# Is initializing the internal state of a PRNG time consuming?

Tags: c++, random, mersenne-twister

I wrote and tested the following program (i.e. timed it using `strace -c` command) and there was no meaningful difference between the execution times of the one that fully seeds the engine and the other one that doesn't.

Here:

```
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>

#define SEEDING_ENABLED 1

int main()
{
    std::random_device rand_dev { };
#if SEEDING_ENABLED == 1
    std::array<int, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
    std::ranges::generate( seed_data, std::ref( rand_dev ) );
    std::seed_seq seq { std::cbegin( seed_data ), std::cend( seed_data ) };
    std::mt19937 engine { seq };
#elif SEEDING_ENABLED == 0
    std::mt19937 engine { rand_dev( ) };
#endif
    std::uniform_int_distribution int_dist { 0, 100 };

    std::array<int, 1000> random_numbers;
    const auto result { std::transform_reduce( std::execution::par,
                                               std::cbegin( random_numbers ), std::cend( random_numbers ),
                                               0, std::plus { },
                                               [ &engine, &int_dist ]( [[ maybe_unused ]] const auto value )
                                               { return int_dist( engine ); } ) };

    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Isn't `std::mt19937` a huge object (`sizeof(std::mt19937) == 5000` on libstdc++) and shouldn't initializing its internal bits take a measurable amount of time? Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Note: The transform-reduce part is there to prevent the compiler from optimizing the initialization part away.

Comment: The size of an object or class have no bearing on what kind of data is initialized at any specific way. Think of `std::vector`, you could create a vector with thousands of large objects, but the size of the vector object itself won't change.

Comment: The lesson here is that it doesn't matter.  The time to initialize the PRNG is insignificant compared to the cost of generating 1000 random numbers.

Comment: @RichardCritten So as far as I understood, basically every time the `operator()` of `rand_dev` is called it returns an `unsigned int` containing 32 random bits, and that gets copied to the array `seed_data` (by the `generate` function). Is this true? And maybe because the rand_dev already gets lots of bits upon its construction, it doesn't need to do another syscall every time its `operator()` is called. Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Hmm. Maybe I should do 10 numbers instead. 1000 is probably taking too long to finish thus hiding the cost of the actual initialization. Also maybe the `chrono` library can measure the time spent in `main` more accurately. I should try that as well.

Comment: The initialization of the `std::mt19937` probably takes dozens of nanoseconds.  Which you ought to only be doing once, when the program starts.

Comment: I'd prefer quickbench over measuring times manually. Especially if measuring manually means you include input/output operations. Here's one run, it seems that initialising `std::mt19997` properly is 500 times slower than doing it the bad way: https://quick-bench.com/q/u7-xCyzZELsoMr46ElCKnY575Ls (note that there are still other things involved, as another run shows 700x difference: https://quick-bench.com/q/u7-xCyzZELsoMr46ElCKnY575Ls - possibly the program has to wait for `/dev/random` to actually generate more entropy)

Comment: Both of your approaches (with either value of `SEEDING_ENABLED`) initialise the PRNG.   The only functional difference is that a value of zero uses default initialisation, and value 1 does something you specify.   There will be an overhead of both, and - depending on what the default initialisation does - there is not necessarily any significant (or even measurable) performance difference between them.   Practically, if you need a sequence of pseudo-random values, you need to accept the overhead of initialising the generator *somehow*.  It is the total impact on your program that matters.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks for the suggestion. I took a look at the link you provided. I found out that you have not specified the `benchmark::DoNotOptimise(engine);` in the body of the `TinyInitialisation`. Take a look at my [version](https://quick-bench.com/q/YKEV_NTT8PjXtAjHnaUgQnUUpmg). It shows a 46X slowdown compared to no initialization and a 38 slowdown compared to the tiny initialization.

Comment: The seeding of a RNG generally doesn't take that much time. Gathering the required entropy to create the seed is usually the part that hurts performance.\

Comment: @MaartenBodewes "*Gathering the required entropy*" You mean initializing the `std::random_device` takes longer?

Comment: Yes, although it of course depends on the implementation how long it takes. I did take a look at the API ref, but that leaves about everything open. Usually implementations won't just rely on RD_RAND though.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I took a look at the docs for the `getrandom` syscall that my program calls once. It fills a buffer with as many bytes as the user wants (up to 32 million - 1). That means 8 million integers. The above program retrieves under 700 integers via the `operator()` of the `rand_dev`. I guess that pretty much tells me that the `operator()` itself has a tiny cost. With that said, full initialization is 40-45X slower than the one-integer initialization.

Comment: @digito_evo " full initialization is 40-45X slower than the one-integer initialization" So internal state after won't be quite good after one-integer initialization. Frankly, I find this idea taking initialization from /def/random to be not good anyway. It is not reproducible and doesn't solve any "good randomness" problem. Use known sequence and warm up your rng, that is it.